# set default selected value in selectize input

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectize.js

I have a form , where I want some default selected value when the page loaded. Something like this:
[image]

Here is my current code which I am using for getting options from remote server:

```
(function () { // function for selectize
            axios.get('/api/tags/', {
                headers: {'Authorization': "JWT " + sessionStorage.getItem('token')}
            }).then(function (response) {
                let nisha = [];
                response.data.map(function (hiren) {
                    let bunny = {'value': '', 'text': ''};
                    bunny['value'] = hiren.name;
                    bunny['text'] = hiren.name;
                    nisha.push(bunny);
                });
                let $select = $('#tags').selectize({
                    delimiter: ';',
                    persist: false,
                    options: nisha,
                    items: tags,
                    create: function(input) {
                        return {
                            value: input,
                            text: input
                        }
                    }
                })
                //var selectize = $select[0].selectize;
                //selectize.setValue('something', true);
            }).catch(function (error) {
                console.error(error);
            })
        })();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass default values in value attribute comma separated like below :

```
<input type="text" id="tags" class="demo-default selectized" value="awesome,neat" tabindex="-1" style="display: none;">
```

And if not working, try creating jsfiddle for this snippet.

Hope this will work.

Comment: This adds only labels but not values. How to preselect tags with values, too? Something lige [{id: '1', name: 'Aples'},{id: '2', name: 'Oranges'},{id: '3', name: 'Bananas'}] ?